# mi consulta preparada no se ejecuta me arroja el error "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

como soluciono el error "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

me lo marca en la parte del modelo en la linea $sql->execute();

al enviar el arreglo le puse cadenas para ver si tenia algun error en las variables pero me siguio marcando el mismo error

En la parte de mi controlador tengo:

```
<?php
   require_once("./modelo/reactivoModelo.php");
   
   class reactivoControlador extends reactivoModelo{
        public function agregarEntradaReactivoControlador() {
            $nombreReactivo=mainModel::limpiarCadenas($_POST['reactivoEntrada-v']);
            $cantidadEntrada=mainModel::limpiarCadenas($_POST['cantidadEntrada-v']);
            $medida=mainModel::limpiarCadenas($_POST['medida-v']);
            $descripcion=mainModel::limpiarCadenas($_POST['descripcion-v']);
             //le pase cadenas para ver si tenia algun error en la variables de arriva, pero me sigue arrojando el error
            $datosEntrada=[
                    "codigoEntrada"=>"fff",
                    "codigoReactivo"=>"fff",
                    "codigoCuenta"=>"hw",
                    "nombreMedida"=>"ddd",
                    "cantidadEntrada"=>"ddd",
                    "fechaEntrada"=>"34rrr",
                    "descripcion"=>"ddd"
                ];
            $guardarEntrada=reactivoModelo::agregarEntradaReactivoModelo($datosEntrada);
            if ($guardarEntrada->rowCount()>=1) {
                echo '<script>alert("datos ingresados");</script>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<script>alert("datos no ingresados");</script>';
            }

   }
?>
```

y en mi modelo tengo lo siguiente:

````
<?php
    require_once("../core/mainModel.php");

    class reactivoModelo extends mainModel {
        protected function agregarEntradaReactivoModelo($datos)
        {
            $sql=mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO entrada_reactivo(codigoEntrada,codigoReactivo,cuentaCodigo,nombreMedida,cantidadEntrada,fechaEntrada,descripcion) 
            VALUES(:codigoEntrada,:codigoReactivo,:cuentaCodigo,:nombreMedida,:cantidadEntrada,:fechaEntrada,:descripcion)");
            $sql->bindParam(":codigoEntrada",$datos['codigoEntrada']);
            $sql->bindParam(":codigoReactivo",$datos['codigoReactivo']);
            $sql->bindParam(":cuentaCodigo",$datos['cuentaCodigo']);
            $sql->bindParam(":nombreMedida",$datos['nombreMedida']);
            $sql->bindParam(":cantidadEntrada",$datos['cantidadEntrada']);
            $sql->bindParam(":fechaEntrada",$datos['fechaEntrada']);
            $sql->bindParam(":descripcion ",$datos['descripcion']);
            $sql->execute();
            return $sql;
        }
    }

?>```
````

Comment: Los parámetros  y las claves del array deben llamarse igual, eso no ocurre en el caso de `codigoCuenta` en `$datosEntrada`, pues en el modelo el parámetro se llama `cuentaCodigo`, así debes ponerlo en `$datosEntrada`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los parámetros  y las claves del array deben llamarse igual, eso no ocurre en el caso de `codigoCuenta` en `$datosEntrada`. Si observas bien, en el modelo el parámetro se llama `cuentaCodigo`, así debes ponerlo en `$datosEntrada` para que coincidan. Haciendo esto el error debería desaparecer.

```
        $datosEntrada=[
                "codigoEntrada"=>"fff",
                "codigoReactivo"=>"fff",
                "cuentaCodigo"=>"hw",
                "nombreMedida"=>"ddd",
                "cantidadEntrada"=>"ddd",
                "fechaEntrada"=>"34rrr",
                "descripcion"=>"ddd"
            ];
```

Por otra parte, se aprecia un espacio de más en el parámetro `:descripcion`, en esta línea:

```
        $sql->bindParam(":descripcion ",$datos['descripcion']);
                                     ^ Este espacio sobra
```

Por tanto, no estaría reconociendo el parámetro como lo escribiste en la instrucción SQL ni como viene en `$datosEntrada`. Debes corregir, quitando ese espacio:

```
        $sql->bindParam(":descripcion",$datos['descripcion']);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar ya corregi lo que me mencionaste y me sigue marcando el mismo error, verifique los nombres en la bd y si son iguales, realmente no se que pueda estar pasando

Comment: @Davidrnk es **imposible** que siga dando el mismo error, a no ser que te hayas equivocado en algo. Edita tu pregunta, poniendo la nueva versión del código para revisar.

Comment: @Davidrnk aquí sobra un espacio: `$sql->bindParam(":descripcion ",$datos['descripcion']);` se aprecia que antes de las comillas hay un espacio en blanco para el parámetro `":descripcion "`, corrige quitando ese espacio así: **`$sql->bindParam(":descripcion",$datos['descripcion']);`** Hay que hilar muy fino con este asunto de los parámetros.

Comment: muchas gracias enserió, la tarde de ayer me pase con ese error, efectivamente eran las dos cosas que me dijiste muchas gracias

Comment: @Davidrnk si la respuesta ha servido para resolver el problema considera marcarla, para que la pregunta no quede como sin resolver. Saludos.